# Slice array diagonally and mask out data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter, slice

My goal is to create a diagonal mask effect... I have part of it down, using `ma.masked_where`, however for the last `contourf (data5)`, I want to mask out just the region in the third plot below where the red line and x are. How might I do that?

I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import ma

data = np.random.rand(5,45,60)
data1 = data[2,0:30,0:30]
x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 30, 1), np.arange(0, 30, 1))
data1 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 30, data1)

data2 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 < 10 , data1) #+
data3 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 25 , data2) #+
data4 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 > 10 , data3)

# my attempt to mask out the top region, above the red line... but then it returns a completely empty plot... 
data5 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > -5 , data4)

plt.contourf(data2)
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()

plt.contourf(data3)
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()

plt.contourf(data4)
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()

plt.contourf(data5)
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

someone suggested:

```
data5 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 > -5 , data4)
```

but the output plot looks like this, which is the not the intention, as it masks out the region I would like to keep:

[image]

Comment: You probably want a subtraction: `data5 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 > -5 , data4)`

Comment: No, unfortunately it masks the section I would like to stay... I will update question and show the output plot

Comment: Well, just use `x2 - y2 < -5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, try this

```
data5 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 < -5 , data4)
```

The result is

[image]